# Assistance with bool tool

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, workflow

I am making a guillotine in Blender as a random beginner's project to get more comfortable with 2.8 and practice a non-destructive way of doing stuff. However, the boolean modifier (using bool-tool) is not working. Blender file will be attached.
[image]

Comment: idk if bumping works but bump

Comment: Hide the mirror modifier and delete the inside faces in edit mode. These are the faces you can't see when the mirror modifier is on. Also, apply the same material on your cube if you want the cut to be textured too